# Sort an excel sheet with specific conditions (vba)

Tags: excel, vba, loops, sorting, grouping

Here is my problem, I have those data on my Sheet1

```
       A      B        C
   1 Name   Account  Amount 
   2 John   HSBC     -20000
   3 Ashley JPM      140000
   4 Rose   BAML     70000
   5 John   DB       10000
   6 Rose   Barclays -25000
   7 Ashley JPM      -3000
```

My goal is to use vba in order to sort lines and group them by name and amount. The result that I'm looking for in Sheet2 is :

```
       A      B        C
   1 Name   Account  Amount 
   2 John   HSBC     -20000
   3 John   DB       10000
   4
   5 Ashley JPM      -3000
   6 Ashley JPM      140000
   7
   8 Rose   Barclays -25000
   9 Rose   BAML     70000
```

I already succeeded in taking the negative values first, but I still have difficulties in taking the rest and leave a blank line between groups.

Here is the code that I started :

```
Option Explicit

Sub sort_account()

Dim list_amount As Range, amount As Range
Dim b As Integer

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Set list_amount = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown))

For Each amount In list_amount
    If amount.Value < 0 Then
        
        b = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 1).Value = amount.Offset(0, -2)
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 2).Value = amount.Offset(0, -1)
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 3).Value = amount
        
    End If
Next amount

Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate

End Sub
```

And this gives me as a result :

```
       A      B        C
   1 Name   Account  Amount 
   2 John   HSBC     -20000
   5 Ashley JPM      -3000
   8 Rose   Barclays -25000
```

I really have difficulties for the rest. Do you have any ideas ? I thank you in advance for that.

Nb : The order doesn't matter, I just want that the first values of each group is the negative amount.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this were my project, I would do it in three distinct steps: Copy all the data from sheet 1 to sheet 2; Sort the data in the preferred order; Insert the blank rows, starting from the bottom.
The following code should do what you’re after.

```
Option Explicit
Sub sort_account()
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

Sheet2.Cells.ClearContents
Sheet1.UsedRange.Copy Sheet2.Range("A1")

Sheet2.Columns("A:C").Sort Key1:=Sheet2.Range("A2"), order1:=xlAscending, _
Key2:=Sheet2.Range("C2"), order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

LastRow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = LastRow To 4 Step -1
    If Sheet2.Cells(i, "A") = Sheet2.Cells(i - 1, 1) Then
        Sheet2.Cells(i - 1, "A").EntireRow.Insert
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Indeed, this was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for your help on that

Answer (score 1):

*If your version of Excel supports Dynamic Arrays then you can do the following*

[image: Sample with highlights]

This solution adds an extra row for each unique name, sorts the new data, and then blanks out the added rows.

E2 is `=CHOOSE({1,2,3},UNIQUE(A2:A7),"temp",99999999)`.  This creates an array with all the unique names in the first column, "temp" in the second column and 99999999 in the third (to be used for sorting).

F6 is `=ROWS(A2:C7)` the count of the rows in the data
F7 is `=ROWS(E2#)` the count of unique names

A10 is `=IF(SEQUENCE(F6+F7)<=F6,A2:C7,INDEX(E2#,SEQUENCE(F6+F7)-F6,SEQUENCE(1,3)))`.  This appends the original data to the new data.

E10 is `=SORT(A10#,{1,3})`, the appended data sorted.

I10 is `=IF(F10:F18="temp","",E10#)`. This blanks out all the temps rows.

*If your version of Excel supports LET you can do this in one cell.*

```
=LET(data,A2:C7,
     tempRows,CHOOSE({1,2,3},UNIQUE(A2:A7),"temp",99999999),
     totalRows,ROWS(data),
     uniqueNames,ROWS(tempRows),
     outRows, SEQUENCE(totalRows+uniqueNames),
     unsorted,IF(outRows<=totalRows,data,INDEX(tempRows,outRows-totalRows,{1,2,3})),
     sorted,SORT(unsorted,{1,3}),
     result, IF(INDEX(sorted,outRows,2)="temp","",INDEX(sorted,outRows,{1,2,3})),
 result)
```

Comment: It worked this way, thanks for your help!